# Is it possible to extend bounty award window?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have a [bounty on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36072350). The bounty has ended and its in the "award the bounty" period:

[image]

I need to extend the award period because (1) I need 3 or 4 days of testing to ensure the work-arounds work as expected, and (2) I don't have the time right now to stop what I am doing and move to Windows testing. With respect to (1), there's no way for me to perform 3 days of testing in the 24-hour window provided by Stack Overflow. With respect to (2), I'll have the block of time in about 5 days.

Is it possible to extend the bounty award window? If so, how do we do it?

---

Here's the bounty FAQ, but it does not discuss the topic: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Answer (score 0):

Bounty questions are intended to draw attention to a question.  The current bounty period is set for 7 days with an additional day of grace period.  There is no way to extend the bounty because you don't have enough time to validate the answers.  You could:

1. Not award the bounty and let the grace period run out, which will award half of the bounty to the highest voted answer above +2 by the community user.  Then test the answers and accept the best answer.
2. Take the time to test the answers regardless of the outcome of the bounty, and award the best answer with an additional bounty after you have evaluated all of the answers.

Comment: With respect to (2), how am I supposed to perform 3 days of testing in 1 day? ***Note well***: I'm interested in the *award period*, and not the bounty.

Answer (score -5):

There isn't *technically* any way to extend the bounty window.

That being said, you could ask a mod:

> They can (at their discretion) refund and cancel a bounty.

(source:[Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189))

Comment: We would not refund a bounty simply so the period could be extended.

Comment: Thanks Laurel. I have had nothing but problems when it comes to working around problems with the Bounty system and getting help from the mod's. I don't count on them as a resource.